# Ошибка pygame.error: video system not initialized

Tags: python, pygame

Много, что попробовал, но проблема остается:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\main.py", line 74, in <module>
    for event in pygame.event.get():
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
pygame.error: video system not initialized

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Код:

```py
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
from OpenGL.GL import *
from OpenGL.GLU import *

# Персонаж
class Character:
    def __init__(self, pos):
        self.pos = pos

def move(self, dx, dy, dz):
    self.pos = (self.pos[0] + dx, self.pos[1] + dy, self.pos[2] + dz)


def init():
    pygame.init()
    pygame.display.init()
    display = (800, 600)
    pygame.display.set_mode(display, DOUBLEBUF | OPENGL)
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)
    gluPerspective(45, (display[0] / display[1]), 0.1, 50.0)
    glTranslatef(0.0, 0.0, -5)


def draw_cube():
        # Отрисовка куба
    vertices = [
        [1, -1, -1],
        [1, 1, -1],
        [-1, 1, -1],
        [-1, -1, -1],
        [1, -1, 1],
        [1, 1, 1],
        [-1, -1, 1],
        [-1, 1, 1]
    ]

    edges = [
        (0, 1),
        (1, 2),
        (2, 3),
        (3, 0),
        (0, 4),
        (1, 5),
        (2, 6),
        (3, 7),
        (4, 5),
        (5, 6),
        (6, 7),
        (7, 4)
    ]

    glBegin(GL_LINES)
    for edge in edges:
        for vertex in edge:
            glVertex3fv(vertices[vertex])
            glEnd()


def handle_keys(character):
    # Обработка нажатия клавиш
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
        character.move(-0.1, 0, 0)
    if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
        character.move(0.1, 0, 0)
    if keys[pygame.K_UP]:
        character.move(0, 0.1, 0)
    if keys[pygame.K_DOWN]:
        character.move(0, -0.1, 0)


def game_loop():
    character = Character((0, 0, 0))
    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()

handle_keys(character)

glRotatef(1, 3, 1, 1)
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)
glPushMatrix()
glTranslatef(*character.pos)
draw_cube()
glPopMatrix()
pygame.display.flip()
pygame.time.wait(10)


init()
game_loop()
```

Comment: Где вы видели чтобы инициализация была почти последним событием?

Comment: Прежде чем вы сможете что-то сделать с pygame, вам необходимо его инициализировать.

Comment: Ответ гуглится очень просто.

Comment: Спасибо, проблема решилась)